# Disable Core Extensions in Magento 1.x

Tags: admin, core

we have a shop that sells physical configurable products. We use a custom payment provider (own extension) and our store is located in Europe.

What core extension can we disable without nasty side effects?

- Mage_Usa
- Mage_Authorizenet
- Mage_Downloadable
- Mage_Authorizenet
- Mage_GiftMessage
- Mage_GoogleCheckout
- Mage_Paygate
- Mage_Poll
- Mage_Usa
- Mage_Weee
- Phoenix_Moneybookers

thanks!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create a file in app/etc/modules called Zzz.xml (so it loaded last) with this content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_Downloadable>
            <active>false</active> 
        </Mage_Downloadable>
        <Mage_Authorizenet>
            <active>false</active> 
        </Mage_Authorizenet>
        <!-- all other modules here -->
    </modules>
</config>
```

There is a chance that you won't be able to disable some of them because there are other modules depending on some of them.

For example if you want to disable `Mage_Usa` you will have to disable `Mage_XmlConnect` also.

[EDIT]
Here is what you can disable:

- Mage_Usa (only if you disable Mage_GoogleCheckout and
  Mage_XmlConnect)
- Mage_Authorizenet
- Mage_Downloadable
- Mage_GiftMessage
- Mage_GoogleCheckout **cannot be disabled** because of this: http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/?issue=14359
- Mage_Paygate (Only if you disable Mage_Paypal, Mage_PaypalUk and Mage_Authorizenet)
- Mage_Poll
- Mage_Weee (only if you disable Mage_XmlConnect also)
- Phoenix_Moneybookers

Comment: Because of tight coupling among core modules it is not so easy. For example, it was a known issue when `Mage_GoogleCheckout` disabling produced fatal error on checkout. Not sure whether it is fixed in the latest 1.7.0.2.

Comment: THanks. THe question is a little about **which** can I disable

Comment: I edited my answer and added some explanations.

Comment: While using this approach don't be confused with the fact that disabled modules will still be present in `System\Advanced\Advanced` screen because it lists all children of `modules` node of global config regardless if module is active or not.

Comment: Is it recommended that this single disable file be renamed from .xml to something else to exclude it from loading during Magento upgrade so all the installers will run to make database changes so you don't run into future problems? I assume that the Mage modules must load in order to fire their installer and database upgrade scripts, correct?

Comment: I don't use Magento Configurable Swatches. Disabling via Mage_ConfigurableSwatches.xml, will this have any side effect? I am looking for performance improvement.

Comment: @Haya. You can disable it.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using 1.7+, you can safely disable `Mage_Poll` and `Phoenix_Moneybookers`. `Mage_Poll` executes code on each page so I usually disable that if I don't need it.

`Mage_Authorizenet`, `Mage_GoogleCheckout` and `Mage_Paygate` should be safe to disable but per the comments some silly bugs may be in there. I would not care about them much, as long as their payment methods are inactive they are basically disabled.

`Mage_GiftMessage` can be turned off via admin settings, so I would not bother with it either.

As for `Mage_Usa`, `Mage_Weee` and `Mage_Downloadable`, do not disable unless you have some hours to spend on testing and fixing. I tried to disable Mage_Usa at some point (Magento 1.5) and it broke most of the shipping modules.

Answer (score 3):

Despite being late with an answer I would like to answer the question from @snh_nl which modules you can disable: Simply all of them, except Mage_Core.

But to disable tight couple modules you need to install another module which takes care that nothing will break. Therefore I've developed: https://github.com/Zookal/magento-mock

Zookal Mock: Transparent auto-detecting of disabled core modules and extensions and providing mock objects for not breaking Magento. Nothing to configure. No class rewrites. Only one observer. Works out of the box. You can even physically remove the files!

One thing to consider: It does not work on command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file:

> app/etc/modules/zzz_disabled_modules.xml.

Replace any module which is used or not used.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Disables modules to improve performance. (most likely unused modules) -->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_Authorizenet>
            <active>false</active>
        </Mage_Authorizenet>
        <Mage_Backup>
            <active>false</active>
        </Mage_Backup>
        <Mage_Compiler>
            <active>false</active>
        </Mage_Compiler>
        <Mage_Centinel>
            <active>false</active>
        </Mage_Centinel>
        <Mage_ConfigurableSwatches>
            <active>false</active>
        </Mage_ConfigurableSwatches>
        <Mage_Downloadable>
            <active>false</active>
        </Mage_Downloadable>
        <Mage_Giftmessage>
            <active>false</active>
        </Mage_Giftmessage>
        <Mage_GoogleCheckout>
            <active>false</active>
        </Mage_GoogleCheckout>
        <Mage_Rating>
            <active>false</active>
        </Mage_Rating>
        <Mage_PaypalUk>
            <active>false</active>
        </Mage_PaypalUk>
        <Mage_Persistent>
            <active>false</active>
        </Mage_Persistent>
        <Mage_Rss>
            <active>false</active>
        </Mage_Rss>
        <Mage_Paypal>
            <active>false</active>
        </Mage_Paypal>
        <Mage_Paygate>
            <active>false</active>
        </Mage_Paygate>
        <Mage_Poll>
            <active>false</active>
        </Mage_Poll>
        <Mage_Weee>
            <active>false</active>
        </Mage_Weee>
        <Mage_Usa>
            <active>false</active>
        </Mage_Usa>
        <Mage_Sendfriend>
            <active>false</active>
        </Mage_Sendfriend>
        <Mage_Tag>
            <active>false</active>
        </Mage_Tag>
        <Mage_Productalert>
            <active>false</active>
        </Mage_Productalert>
        <Phoenix_Moneybookers>
            <active>false</active>
        </Phoenix_Moneybookers>
        <Mage_XmlConnect>
            <active>false</active>
        </Mage_XmlConnect>
    </modules>
</config>
```