# Disabling modules - performance improvement?

Tags: module, magento-1, performance, core

This question has 2 parts:

1. Does disabling core modules improve overall performance of the store and if so, do they need disabled in the admin (i.e. disable frontend output) or disabled via config.xml for this performance improvement to be seen.
2. If there is a performance improvement to be gained, which modules on a stock, CE 1.7.0.2 build can be safely disabled, via the method answered in part 1.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

1. Yes it does. First of all, less modules means less code to (potentially) load and process. Next to that, a lot of modules, like for example the Mage_Rss module run a lot of code in the background like forcing reindexes on certain events.

   On the method best to use: disabling a module using `System > Configuration > Advanced` only suppresses the output of a module while still including the code of that Module in the shop. This is handy when you don't want a modules functionality but you need it's Models or Blocks for example because other (3th party) extensions depend on it. Disabling it using `app/etc/modules/*.xml` will completely remove it from the installation so performance wise this is the best option.
2. I usually disable the following extension via XMl

   - Mage_Rss
   - Mage_PayPalUk
   - Mage_Tag (when not used in a project)
   - Mage_Poll (cause who uses polls anyway)
   - Phoenix_Moneybookers
   - Mage_Sendfriend
   - Mage_Rating (when not used in a project)
   - Mage_Bundle (again, if not required by client)
   - Mage_Downloadable (see above)

   and via `System > Congiguration > Advanced` the `Mage_Adminnotification` which suppresses those annoying popups in the backend.

   You can probably disable several more core extensions depending on what you're using or not. Just make sure that you don't compromise the stability of Magento. I guess this will take some trial and error.

Comment: Is there a way to disable them without changing the core xml files?

Comment: If it doesn't already have it's own XML file you can go ahead and create it, just create `app/etc/module/Mage_Rss.xml` for example and just be sure you add the **codePool** (core) and **active** (false) tag

Comment: I maybe confused things just then :).  I mean to say that can i disable Mage_Centinel for example, without amending Mage_Centinel.xml i.e. use my own xml file to disable it.  That way I would not be changing core code

Comment: Ahhh okay, I misunderstood. well you probably can disable it since all XML files are merged into one so if you add it in your extensions config.xml tag it should get pickup up but in my opinion it's 'cleaner' to do it from the `app/etc/modules` directory. But thats just me :)

Comment: If you want to disable other modules in your own module's XML, remember Magento's module load order. If you're disabling `Mage_Rss` in a module named `Another_Module`, you'll find that it's not going to work. You'll have to put it in a module with a name alphabetically *after* `Mage_Rss`.

Comment: @pspahn actually, disabling in `Another_Module` will work, because `Mage` modules has higher priority.

Comment: In my opinion its bad idea to disable modules output. You will not get much performance and at the same time you (or another developer) can get a lot of troubles during debug. I faced with situation when the model Mage_Tax was disabled in (system/advanced) and part of totals block disappeared from the cart. The main disadvantage of the disabling output is no errors. Because magento think that it's expected behavior. But developer think what's happening? Better setup varnish and you will get much more that disabling output

Comment: Before disabling polls remember to delete the sample poll "Choose colors"; I've found third-party modules who can show poll contents even if the module is disabled.

Comment: Before disabling polls remember to delete the sample poll "Choose colors"; I've found third-party modules who can show poll contents even if the module is disabled.

Answer (score 14):

Despite being late with an answer I would like to answer the question

1. You gain even more performance if you physically remove the files.
2. Simply all of them, except `Mage_Core` ;-)

But to disable tight couple modules you need to install another module which takes care that nothing will break. Therefore I've developed: https://github.com/Zookal/magento-mock

Zookal Mock: Transparent auto-detecting of disabled core modules and extensions and providing mock objects for not breaking Magento. Nothing to configure. No class rewrites. Only one observer. Works out of the box. You can even physically remove the files!

E.g. when you disable `Mage_Wishlist` or `Mage_Newsletter` your *Backend -> Customer -> Customer edit* will throw weird errors. Therefore use the Mock extension!

You can even uninstall old Payment modules which have entries in the `sales_flat_order_payment` table and normally break your *Backend -> Sales -> Order View* but the Mock extension has a transparent work around for you.

One thing to consider: It does not work on command line.

Answer (score 10):

See [Marius' answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/2664/18509) regarding a simple and quick XML way of disabling modules. Create a single file `zzz_Disabled_Modules.xml` with the contents

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_Rss>
            <active>false</active>
        </Mage_Rss>
        <Mage_PaypalUk>
           <active>false</active>
        </Mage_PaypalUk>
        <Phoenix_Moneybookers>
            <active>false</active>
        </Phoenix_Moneybookers>
        <!-- all other modules here -->
    </modules>
</config>
```

Imagine! A .gitignore for Magento modules!

With this you can easily see which modules you have enabled/disabled at a glance.

Answer (score 2):

As @Sander Mangel says disabling modules defiantly can have a big performance gain, although what you disable really is a store-by-store thing.  There's normally plenty that you don't need though.  If you're not using whishlist disabling `Mage_Wishlist` makes quite a difference.

Another gain is disabling `Mage_Log`.  This may be better done through local.xml though.