# "My Account" page goes blank after user places order

Tags: orders, layout, template, xml, customer-account

In doing some testing on my site I noticed that for one of my test accounts the "My Account" page was mostly empty. Everything below the top navbar was missing except a couple sentences of text.

But I also noticed that on a couple of other test accounts, it was still showing all the usual account info/links.  Eventually I realized the difference is that I had tested the ordering process with the first account.

I set up a brand new account and was able to see the My Account page right off the bat. I place a quick test order, and sure enough everything useful on the account page disappeared.  (The "My Orders" page is also completely blank below the navbar, and I am assuming at this point that it is the same or at least a closely related issue).

I tried switching to the default theme and had the same problem.

Unfortunately I'm too new to Magento to have a clue where to look. I'm guessing I need to look at an XML file somewhere (or maybe a phtml file?), but I'm not sure where or what I'm looking for specifically.

I'm using Magento 1.9.0.1

Any ideas?

Below are a couple of screenshots taken from before and after placing the order with the test account.

Here's before:
[image: Before placing an order]

And here's after:
[image: After placing an order]

In the exception log, I see this error repeated over and over with a new timestamp each time:

```
2014-09-25T14:16:25+00:00 ERR (3):
exception 'Mage_Api2_Exception' with message 'oauth_problem=parameter_absent&oauth_parameters_absent=oauth_consumer_key' in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Auth/Adapter/Oauth.php:61
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Auth/Adapter.php(83): Mage_Api2_Model_Auth_Adapter_Oauth->getUserParams(Object(Mage_Api2_Model_Request))
#1 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Auth.php(59): Mage_Api2_Model_Auth_Adapter->getUserParams(Object(Mage_Api2_Model_Request))
#2 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Server.php(152): Mage_Api2_Model_Auth->authenticate(Object(Mage_Api2_Model_Request))
#3 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Server.php(103): Mage_Api2_Model_Server->_authenticate(Object(Mage_Api2_Model_Request))
#4 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/api.php(67): Mage_Api2_Model_Server->run()
#5 {main}

    2014-09-25T14:27:28+00:00 ERR (3):
exception 'Mage_Api2_Exception' with message 'oauth_problem=parameter_absent&oauth_parameters_absent=oauth_consumer_key' in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Auth/Adapter/Oauth.php:61
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Auth/Adapter.php(83): Mage_Api2_Model_Auth_Adapter_Oauth->getUserParams(Object(Mage_Api2_Model_Request))
#1 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Auth.php(59): Mage_Api2_Model_Auth_Adapter->getUserParams(Object(Mage_Api2_Model_Request))
#2 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Server.php(152): Mage_Api2_Model_Auth->authenticate(Object(Mage_Api2_Model_Request))
#3 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Server.php(103): Mage_Api2_Model_Server->_authenticate(Object(Mage_Api2_Model_Request))
#4 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/api.php(67): Mage_Api2_Model_Server->run()
#5 {main}
```

At first glance I'm not even sure what Mage_Api2 is or why it's getting upset at me for not using oauth, but that at least gives me a better direction to sniff...

Edit again:

I found this [q&a saying it was okay for me to disable those modules](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19079/what-default-modules-i-can-disable).  So I disabled both Mage_Api2 and Mage_OAuth hoping that would fix it.

I have the same problem, and now this is the error showing in the log:

```
    2014-09-25T14:57:28+00:00 ERR (3):
exception 'Mage_Api2_Exception' with message 'Server can not understand Accept HTTP header media type.' in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Renderer.php:70
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Server.php(91): Mage_Api2_Model_Renderer::factory(Array)
#1 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/api.php(67): Mage_Api2_Model_Server->run()
#2 {main}
```

Not sure why I'm still having errors with Mage_Api2 tryin to do stuff.  Does that mean some other module is trying to use MageApi2?

system.log shows these errors which have time stamps that I think line up with the exceptions in exception.log - you can see where we switched to a new error, but I thought info from the old error might still be helpful.

```
2014-09-25T12:01:42+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct():                                                        ^  in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2014-09-25T14:18:51+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 71: parser error : xmlParseEntityRef: no name  in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2014-09-25T14:18:51+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct():             &lt;title&gt;Free Bonus with Bulk Images Upload &amp; SEO Extension&lt;/title&gt;  in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2014-09-25T14:18:51+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct():                                                        ^  in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2014-09-25T14:51:28+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Renderer.php on line 58
2014-09-25T14:57:28+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Renderer.php on line 58
2014-09-25T15:03:28+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Renderer.php on line 58
2014-09-25T15:09:28+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Renderer.php on line 58
```

My untrained eyes see a line referencing the bulk image uploading extension I used. Not sure yet if it is part of the problem or just got caught in the mix. *[EDIT] I disabled the bulk image module as well as another one from the same developer with no change in the problem or the error outputs.*

Comment: have you install any module related to customer?

Comment: There's a server side error. Did you check your PHP logs? You can also have a look in the magento logs var/logs/exception.log

Comment: @alex.ayg - I did... but at 5am with no sleep I came to the conclusion that there wasn't an error logged in there that was relevant.  Now with a couple hours of sleep, I'm not as sure, so I'll edit my question :)

Comment: @KeyulShah - I don't think I've installed any that were supposed to modify or customer data, though some of the extensions seem to have features beyond what was mentioned, and I can't pretend to be completely sure how they all interact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Alright, I'll set this as an answer rather than further editing my question, because I was able to get the "My Account" page back to normal.  If anyone that has actually used the extension causing my problem and knows what I might do to fix it, I'm certainly still open to help - but I'm putting in a ticket with the developer in the meantime.*

I found source the problem. It was with an extension called Moogento_PickPack (Which is a shame, I was/am pretty excited about that extension. Hopefully the developer can help me out with this.) Disabling that extension fixed it.

***But here's a more useful answer to anyone who finds themselves in a similar situation but maybe with a different set of extensions than I have:***

Along with the troubleshooting mentioned in my question edits, I learned how to individually disable the extensions one by one to see which one may be causing it.  Seems fairly simple, but I didn't know how to do it yet, so I'm sure someone else out there hasn't learned it yet either.

There are a whole slew of .xml files in this directory: magento/htdocs/app/etc/modules/

Each one of them corresponds to a module/extension (some from the core, some that you've installed).

When you open one up, it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Oauth
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2014 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
-->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_Oauth>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>core</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Core/>
            </depends>
        </Mage_Oauth>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Change the  block to false instead of true:

```
<active>false</active>
```

And the module is now disabled.  Doing that one by one to each of the modules you've installed (and potentially some of the core ones) should help you troubleshoot which one is causing problems for you.

As I mentioned above, [here's a discussion of which of the default Magento modules you can safely disable](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19079/what-default-modules-i-can-disable) in case you need that for your testing.

Answer (score 1):

Quick update if anyone is using pickPack and encounters this issue; the latest version (3.4.55) is confirmed as not having this issue. We're redone the way we interact with email to make it more predictable.

ps. If you're trying to temporarily disable extensions, you may find it faster to rename the /etc/modules xml file to eg. '.xml.off' (and clearing cache). I find that easier to keep track of which are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I had the EXACT same problem!

In app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/moogento/pickpack.xml
Comment out everything related to customer account.

Hope that works for you also.

Comment: Given the accepted answer, I reckon this would've worked as well, so undo the downvote. Marius needs the points.