# Disable Basic Modules to Improve Performance

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, third-party-module

I want to disable modules I don't use to improve performace on System -> Advanced -> Advanced

I found this [Disabling modules - performance improvement?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8746/disabling-modules-performance-improvement)

but only few modules are mention and I think there are other basic modules we can disable

Is there a link which explain each module? So I can decide I disable or not

or any recommend setting?

e.g.) I still can't figure what Mage_Usa do

[image]

Also anyone have used this? curious this works well

'Transparent auto detecting of disabled core modules and providing mock objects for not breaking Magento.'

https://github.com/Zookal/magento-mock

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to point out that setting `Disabled` for a certain module in `System > Configuration > Advanced > Disable Modules Output` will not actually disable that module. It will, as the name suggest, disable modules output.

```
final public function toHtml()
{
    Mage::dispatchEvent('core_block_abstract_to_html_before', array('block' => $this));
    if (Mage::getStoreConfig('advanced/modules_disable_output/' . $this->getModuleName())) {
        return '';
    }
....
```

Modules are disabled in `app/etc/modules` by setting `<active>false</active>` for specific module.

There is already a good post on the topic here: 
[What Default Modules I can disable?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19079/what-default-modules-i-can-disable)