# Disabling modules in Mage_All.xml breaks backend in Magnet 1.9.3.8

Tags: magento-1.9

I did not change the core files. I created a zzz_deactivate.xml and disabled the modules in this file.

But as explained by @Jonathan Eltgroth in this thread [What Default Modules I can disable?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19079/what-default-modules-i-can-disable) disabling a module in Mage_All.xml breaks the backend after flushing the cache.

How can I still completely disable the suggested modules in this thread for better performance without breaking anything?

Comment: Please explain more about the question. Did you disabled the Mage_All? If yes then please enable it.

Comment: No, in Mage_All you can disable modules like Mage_Rss, Mage_Rating, Mage_Bundle, .... but doing so breaks the backend as explained by @Jonathan Eltgroth in the linked thread.