# Magento Blocks HTML output keeps invalidating - any downside to disabling?

Tags: cache

My Blocks HTML output Cache keeps invalidating almost as quickly as I am refreshing it.

I have come across 3rd party modules that allow you to refresh this with a regular cron job, but I don't want to add unnecessary modules to my installation.

**Is there any negative effect of disabling this particular cache?**

Comment: Mage_Rss may be to blame: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8746/disabling-modules-performance-improvement

Comment: I just checked and Mage_Rss is already disabled.

Comment: You say "When you enable the cache block html these blocks are generated only the first time and then retrieved from cache all the next times.
******Note: by default only few blocks uses cache."****** What blocks or type of blocks use cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cache system is there for one reason: performance improvements.
So disabling any kind of cache will have an impact on performances.

In this particular scenario, disabling `block html` cache, all blocks that use cache will be re-regenerated every time (page load), adding extra CPU load.
When you enable the cache `block html` these blocks are generated only the first time and then retrieved from cache all the next times.
Note: by default only few blocks uses cache.

So disabling this cache will produce the effect that all the pages that has this kind of blocks will be slower.

It is much better to have a module that refresh `invalid` cache instead of disabling it