# Why would the Blocks HTML output cache need to be refreshed daily?

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, redis

I've noticed that our Blocks HTML output cache regularly needs to be refreshed, every day even when no one has been working on the Backend of Magento?

Why would this cache become invalid so frequently when no one has been updating CMS pages, static blocks, products etc?

What happens when the cache is invalid?  Does Magento go to the file system rather than the cache when a cache is invalid?

We're using redis Backend cache, I'm thinking that perhaps redis does not have enough memory allocated to it.

Could this have something to do with this bug regarding Blocks HTML output cache on 1.9 https://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/870

Comment: Have you looked at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/50064/magento-blocks-html-output-keeps-invalidating-any-downside-to-disabling ?

Comment: @Prateek, yes but it doesn't really answer what I'ma asking

Comment: Yes, it doesn't answer all the parts of your question, but it does have answer for "What happens when the cache is invalid? Does Magento go to the file system rather than the cache when a cache is invalid?"

Comment: @Holy Block caching is used for more than just CMS pages. Are you making updates to products or categories?

Comment: @brentwpeterson, no it needs to be refreshed every morning after about 14 hours of no one touching the backend.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?  Does it happen when you save cache to your local folder? (Not REDIS?)

Comment: @brentwpeterson, haven't figured it out yet. You point about redis is interesting, I'm not going to disable redis on production but will try it on UAT and see if it occurs.

Comment: @Holy Same behaviour here, on CE 1.9.2.2, not using redis now, but using Lesti FPC. Every morning `blocks html output` needs to be refreshed. It looks like some cron task is invalidating this cache at nights? did you figure out? I will try to dig in

Comment: @Marc, not yet.  I have a hunch that if I increase the amount of memory available to Redis it may sort it out.  I don't really know how Lesti FPC works but I don't think it would be resonsible for `blocks html output` as that is part of Magento's backend cache.  Lesti looks good though, how have you found it?  I'll update my question when I do more tests and see how increasing the memory works out.  It may be an issue with 1.9.2.2

Comment: @Holy Agree, an issue in 1.9.2.2. Found it browsing for a FPC solution for CE, far less complex than implementing any varnish nginx solution... worked very nicely on development and we are giving it a try now. Have to say awesome results for now. Note it'll need adjustments for non-cached content and specially layered navigation, check: [gordon lesti s site](https://gordonlesti.com/projects/lestifpc/) and the explanation on uri params.

Comment: @brentwpeterson, I've tested it out and the issue is also occurring when the cache is store in var/cache (not redis)

Comment: @brentwpeterson, could this have something to do with this reported magento bug I wonder https://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/870