# List of not-used core modules that can be turn off with no harm

Tags: magento2, module, performance

Reffering to this [this topic for Magento 1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8746/disabling-modules-performance-improvement), maybe it would be useful to prepare a list of core Magento 2 modules that can be turn off or completely removed with no harm for our store, because they are hardly used.

To begin with some propositions:

- `Magento_Ups` or `Magento_Dhl` or `Magento_Fedex` (if our client won't use them shipment)
- `Magento_Paypal` - as above
- `Magento_AdminNotification` (sometimes annoying)
- all modules with `Import/Export` - if we don't migrate our store from Magento 1
- `Magento_Bundle` or `Magento_Downloadable` or `Magento_GroupedProduct` - if won't be used
- `Magento_GiftMessage` - (if not used)
- `Magento_Rss` - if not used
- `Magento_Sitemap`

And here some questionable ones - if someone has experience with them, please let know if they are useful for anything:

- `Magento_Marketplace`
- `Magento_Msrp`
- `Magento_NewRelicReporting`
- `Magento_OfflineShipping` & `Magento_OfflinePayments`
- `Magento_SampleData`
- `Magento_Swagger`
- `Magento_Usps`
- `Magento_Vault`

Comment: I believe that `Magento_NewRelicReporting` is merely an integration with the New Relic application performance profiling service, so I'd definitely try to turn that one off. Also, `Magento_SampleData` is merely sample data (products, customers, orders, etc.), and so that can definitely be turned off.

Comment: Guys - any update in case of Magento 2.3?

Comment: @bartosz-kubicki in one of my **Magento v.2.3.1** I have disabled these https://pastebin.com/z5BmTT4H without a problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's a list of what I think the modules do, it might help knowing what you can try to disable.

Important note: **please check the module dependencies when disabling modules because some dependencies may be breaking.**

- AdminNotification: **can be disabled**. But it's useful to get the last security information.
- AdvancedPricingImportExport: I reckon this one can be disabled if you don't use the Import/Export feature or the advanced pricing.
- Authorization: **cannot be disabled** it's the module that handles the ACL
- Authorizenet: **can be disabled** if you don't use Authorize.net
- Backend: **cannot be disabled** it handles the backend.
- Backup: **can be disabled** if you don't use the Magento backup feature.
- BrainTree: **can be disabled** if you don't use BrainTree
- Bundle: **can be disabled** if you don't use bundle products.
- BundleImportExport: **can be disabled** if you don't use bundle products via Import/Export
- CacheInvalidate: **can be disabled** if you don't use Varnish cache (but you should!)
- Captcha: **can be disabled** if you don't use captchas
- Catalog: well I reckon it can be disabled but why would you ?
- CatalogImportExport: **can be disabled** if you don't use Import/Export for the catalog
- CatalogInventory: **cannot be disabled**
- CatalogRule: I reckon it could be disabled if you don't use catalog price rules
- CatalogRuleConfigurable: **can be disabled** if you don't use catalog price rule with configurable products
- CatalogSearch: keep it ;)
- CatalogUrlRewrite: same for this one
- CatalogWidget: this one **can be disabled** if you don't use the catalog widget product list
- Checkout: keep it
- CheckoutAgreements: **can be disabled** if you don't use the checkout agreements.
- Cms: ain't sure if it can really be disabled if you don't use CMS features to be honest.
- CmsUrlRewrite: see above
- Config: **cannot be disabled** it handles the System Configuration feature.
- ConfigurableImportExport: **can be disabled** if you don't use configurable with the Import/export feature
- ConfigurableProduct: **can be disabled** if you don't use configurable products
- Contact: **can be disabled** if you don't use the contact page
- Cookie: keep it ;)
- Cron: same here
- CurrencySymbol: I think it **can be disabled** if you don't use multiple currencies
- Customer: well ^^
- CustomerImportExport: **can be disabled** if you don't use the Import/Export feature with customers
- Deploy: I reckon it depends on your deployment methods but this is the module that handles the deploy CLI commands
- Developer: **can be disabled** in production I reckon, it provides several CLI commands for developers.
- Dhl: **can be disabled** if you don't use DHL
- Directory: I reckon it **cannot be disabled** as it handles the management of countries and regions.
- Downlodable: **can be disabled** if you don't use downloadable products.
- DownlodableImportExport: **can be disabled** if you don't use downlodable products with the Import/Export feature.
- Eav: **cannot be disabled**
- Email: **cannot be disabled**
- EncryptionKey: **should not be disabled** because it handles the advanced encryption model to protect passwords/sensitive data.
- Fedex: **can be disabled** if you don't use FedEx.
- GiftMessage: **can be disabled** if you don't use gift messages.
- GoogleAdwords: **can be disabled** if you don't use Adwords.
- GoogleAnalytics: **can be disabled** if you don't use Analytics (who does that ?)
- GoogleOptimizer: **can be disabled** if you don't use Google Experiment (A/B testing) with Google Analytics
- GroupedImportExport: **can be disabled** if you don't use grouped products with the Import/Export feature.
- GroupedProduct: **can be disabled** if you don't use grouped products.
- ImportExport: **can be disabled** if you don't use the Import/Export feature at all.
- Indexer: keep it
- Integration: pretty sure it **can be disabled** if you don't use the web API.
- LayeredNavigation: **can be disabled** if you don't use the Layered navigation.
- Marketplace: **can be disabled** it displays partners of Magento in the backend.
- MediaStorage: keep it
- Msrp: I reckon it **can be disabled** if you don't use the MSRP feature of Magento.
- Multishipping: **can be disabled** if you don't use the "ship to multiple addresses" feature.
- NewRelicReporting: **can be disabled** if you don't use NewRelic.
- Newsletter: **can be disabled** if you don't use the newsletter feature of Magento.
- OfflinePayments: **can be disabled** if you don't use the following payment methods: bank transfer, cash on delivery, check/money order and purchase order.
- OfflineShipping: **can be disabled** if you don't use the following shipping methods: free shipping, flat rate, table rates and store pickup.
- PageCache: keep it
- Payment: same
- Paypal: **can be disabled** if you don't use PayPal.
- Persistent: **can be disabled** if you don't use the persistence feature of Magento.
- ProductAlert: **can be disabled** if you don't use the product alerts feature.
- ProductVideo: **can be disabled** if you don't use videos for your products.
- Quote: keep it
- Reports: I reckon it **can be disabled** if you don't use the Magento reports.
- RequireJs: keep it
- Review: **can be disabled** if you don't use the review system.
- Rss: **can be disabled** if you don't use RSS
- Rule: it's the abstract module extended by the sales rule, catalog rule etc.. Theorically if you don't use any of the rules you **can disable it**
- Sales: keep it
- SalesRule: **can be disabled** if you don't use the shopping cart rules.
- SalesSequence: should be kept. It's responsible for the sequences processing in Sales module.
- SampleData: **can be disabled** if you don't use the sample data
- Search: keep it
- Security: keep it
- SendFriend: **can be disabled** if you don't use the send to friend feature.
- Shipping: keep it
- Sitemap: you can **disable it** if you don't want to manage the sitemap.
- Store: keep it
- Swagger: I think it **can be disabled** if you don't want to check the Magento REST API in a user friendly format.
- Swatches: **can be disabled** if you don't use the swatches
- SwatchesLayeredNavigation: **can be disabled** if you don't use the swatches in your layered navigation
- Tax: keep it except if you live in a tax free world. In that case, send me an invite to your world.
- TaxImportExport: **can be disabled** if you don't use the Import/Export feature with taxes.
- Theme: keep it
- Translation: theorically you **can disable it** if you don't need translations
- Ui: keep it
- Ups: **can be disabled** if you don't UPS
- UrlRewrite: keep it
- User: keep it
- Usps: **can be disabled** if you don't use USPS
- Variable: **can be disabled** if you don't use the custom variables feature.
- Vault: **can be disabled** if you don't use Vault.
- Version: **should be disabled** because it allows anyone to check your Magento version by accessing `/magento_version`
- Webapi: **can be disabled** if you don't use the REST and SOAP web services.
- WebapiSecurity: **should not be disabled** if you do use REST and SOAP web services.
- Weee: **can be disabled** if you don't wee/fixed product taxes
- Widget: **can be disabled** if you don't use widgets
- Wishlist: **can be disabled** if you don't use the wishlist feature.

Comment: if Review module disable at that time in admin product page, js error are occure. have you checked that?

Comment: @Rakesh no as I said you need to check the module dependencies before disabling any module

Answer (score 8):

Theoretically you should be able to disable any module if you also disable the module's dependencies.
You should be able to see all dependencies by running the cli command `bin/magento info:dependencies:show-modules`. It will generate a csv file with all dependencies between the modules.
Ideally this would be a tree like structure, and disabling one branch completely should work, but this is real life, it does not work like that.
There are some modules that have circular dependencies. "A depends on B which depends on C which depends on A" (this is still a small scenario. You can get chains bigger than that).
Here you cannot disable a module unless you disable the full circle.
But you cannot do that from the UI when installing the module. You have to do it manually before installing it.
You can check all circular dependencies using this command `bin/magento info:dependencies:show-modules`.  Again, you will get a csv file with all the circular dependencies explained.
but even if you disable the full circles, you might still get problems because of some undeclared dependencies and/or some dependencies declared in the wrong modules.
I made a presentation about disabling core modules about a year ago for MagetTitansIT.  You can find the [slides here](https://github.com/tzyganu/MageTitansIt2016/blob/master/Magento-2-as-a-CMS.pdf).
It may be a little outdated because some things got fixed in the past year, but the idea and the main problem still remain.

Comment: `bin/magento info:dependencies:show-module` seems to be extremely useful! I will check that slides!

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is the best thing I have found so far: https://www.integer-net.com/make-magento-2-small-again/