# Magento 2 : Disable Default Modules for Performance

Tags: magento2, module, performance

We are trying to improve performance of our Magento 2 stores. But which default modules are there to be disabled without getting errors?

Currently I have this list:

```
Magento_AdminNotification
Magento_Backup
Magento_Vault
Magento_CheckoutAgreements
Magento_Dhl
Magento_Downloadable
Magento_Fedex
Magento_GoogleAdwords
Magento_GroupedImportExport
Magento_GroupedProduct
Magento_DownloadableImportExport
Magento_InstantPurchase
Magento_Marketplace
Magento_Multishipping
Magento_NewRelicReporting
Magento_Paypal
Magento_ReleaseNotification
Magento_ProductAlert
Dotdigitalgroup_Email
Magento_Rss
Magento_Signifyd
Magento_Authorizenet
Magento_Ups
Magento_SampleData
Magento_Usps
Magento_Braintree
Magento_Weee
Shopial_Facebook
Temando_Shipping
Magento_SendFriend
Magento_Review
Magento_ReviewAnalytics
Magento_WishlistAnalytics
Magento_GoogleOptimizer
```

Answer (score 5):

I've had good success with disabling unused modules. Everyone will have different needs based on their store requirements.

Run the following command to see all modules active and disabled.

```
    php bin/magento module:status
```

Once you have worked out which ones you wish to disable use the following;

```
    php bin/magento module:disable Magento_SampleData
```

Once all your modules are disabled run the following comands;

```
    php bin/magento setup:di:compile
    php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

The following modules below are currently disabled on my store.

- Magento_SampleData
- Magento_Dhl
- Magento_Weee
- Magento_Fedex
- Magento_Marketplace
- Magento_Signifyd
- Magento_Ups
- Magento_Usps
- Magento_Braintree
- Magento_Version
- Amasty_SocialLogin
- Amazon_Core
- Amazon_Login
- Amazon_Payment
- Dotdigitalgroup_Email
- Hackathon_EAVCleaner
- Klarna_Core
- Klarna_Ordermanagement
- Klarna_Kp
- Temando_Shipping
- Vertex_Tax

Answer (score 2):

I think you already have the store in production mode, right?

If you do not use Magento Business Intelligence service you may want to disable that, I find the admin performance improves. You can do that in the admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Advanced Reporting -> Advanced Reporting Service -> disable.

I also disable Shopial_Facebook for admin performance improvements (it is for Facebook integration that I usually do not use).

Then depending on what I need I usually have a look at the list mentioned in the answer of [List of not-used core modules that can be turn off with no harm](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151135/list-of-not-used-core-modules-that-can-be-turn-off-with-no-harm).