# How to disable mage_rss

Tags: rss

So I've read numerous reports that mage_rss can sometimes lead to slow shopping carts. I know it's handled through app>code>core>rss, but which file do I need to disable to completely disably mage_rss?

I know that I can disable it from configuration>advanced>advanced, but I know that just stops it's output on the screen and doesn't completely disable it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento stores its module configuration within the app/etc/modules folder.

You will have a Mage_All.xml file within that which contains the bulk of the Magento core module declarations.

Look for the Mage_Rss section and change the  tag to `<active>false</active>`,

```
       <Mage_Rss>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>core</codePool>
         <depends>
            <Mage_Catalog/>
            <Mage_CatalogInventory/>
            <Mage_Sales/>
            <Mage_SalesRule/>
            <Mage_Wishlist/>
         </depends>
    </Mage_Rss>
```

The Modules listed in the depends is the core modules that the RSS feed relies on.

Comment: Keep all the Mage_ module disables in one place so they're easy to find =>[Disable Core Extensions](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/2663/disable-core-extensions/2664#2664)